# What's the Benefit of Using Layer Weight?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I just don't see the difference using Facing and Fresnel, or Layer Weight as a whole in my node editor.

Is it a big difference using it, is it useful for distant objects?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29161/relation-between-fresnel-ior-and-layerweight-blend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many big differences, among which are that:

- Fresnel depends on the face normals of your mesh - it will not work with inconsistent or incorrect normals;
- The Layer Weight node allows for a smooth [blend between the two](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/layer_weight.html);

Depending on what you wish to achieve, it may be better to use a specific one, but generally, you'll want to use the Fresnel node, as it's *more physically accurate*.

Comment: Is it effective when far away?

Comment: @BinaryGreen What, the Layer Weight? It should

Comment: @someonewithpc what do you mean by 'between the two' (2nd bullet point) could you add a link?

Comment: @stacker Between the two parts of the mask. Both ways generate, basically, a mask to use for controlling mix nodes - black and white - , but layer weight blends the white and the black parts, to give a smoother transition